# Error: NG0302: The pipe 'myFilter' could not be found! when running ng test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

In my Angular project (v12) I use various custom pipes in different components. Everything is declared in `app.modules.ts`, however running `ng test` throws `Error: NG0302: The pipe 'myFilter' could not be found!` only for some (most recently created/used) pipes/components.

For example I use one pipe in Component1 and the tests all pass, however if I use it in Component2, running `ng test` it suddenly throws an error and component creation fails (`serve`and `build` are fine). Both `*spec.ts` files look exactly the same (as created) and with everything being declared in `app.modules.ts` I don't understand why

1. it fails at all (afaik in that case you don't need to declare them in `*.spec.ts`)
2. only fails for some components.

Thankful for any explanation/hints, the linked error page unfortunately doesn't help much.

(The app was originally created with version 8 and now uses version 12.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIX:**
Do the following changes:

1. In your local module add your `MyFilter` pipe in `declarations`.
2. In `spec` file add `MyFilter` pipe's class name in `declarations`.
3. Add in `providers` as well if you get error like `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[PipeName -> PipeName]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for PipeName!`.

**Your local spec file where error came**

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [...],
            providers: [...],
            declarations: [
              ...
              MyFilter // Add your pipe here
            ]
        });
    });
```

**Your local module file where your current component is running**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..., MyFilter], Include your pipe here
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```